# Jaccard similarity for array of shape (411, 13) gives an error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (411,) (13,)

Tags: python, numpy, loops, similarity

I want to write a code of calculating jaccard similarity with the use of [these formulas.](https://www.iiisci.org/journal/pdv/sci/pdfs/GS315JG.pdf)

My original dataset is in shape (411, 13)

However, it works like this:

```
# Read in the data from CSV file
data = pd.read_csv("my file.CSV", index_col=0).values.astype(int)

np.zeros((n_instances, n_instances)) 
for i in range(n_instances):
     for j in range(n_instances):
         if i == j:
             jaccard_similarities[i, j] = 1.0
         else:
             a = np.sum(data[i] & data[j])
             b = np.sum(data[i] & ~data[j])
             c = np.sum(~data[i] & data[j])
             d = np.sum(~data[i] & ~data[j])
             if a + b + c == 0:
                 jaccard_similarities[i, j] = 0
             else:
                 jaccard_similarities[i, j] = a / (a + b + c)
```

But this gives me an array of shape (411, 411).

I want to get and array of shape (411, 13) as original data. Is that even possible? I tried iterating over different things but it gives me an error:

```
n_instances = data.shape[0]
n_features = data.shape[1]
jaccard_similarities = np.zeros((n_instances, n_features))

for i in range(n_instances):
    for j in range(n_features):
        a = np.sum(data[:, j] & data[i, :])
        b = np.sum(data[:, j] & ~data[i, :])
        c = np.sum(~data[:, j] & data[i, :])
        d = np.sum(~data[:, j] & ~data[i, :])
        if a + b + c == 0:
            jaccard_similarities[i, j] = 0
        else:
            jaccard_similarities[i, j] = a / (a + b + c)
```

The error i get:

> a = np.sum(data[:, i] & data[j, :]) ValueError: operands could not be
> broadcast together with shapes (411,) (13,)

Comment: Do you create `jaccard_similarities` as `np.zeros((411,411))`?

Comment: Jacard Similarity is pairwise measure, so for each row you have 411 measurements, hence the 411x411. 
What do you expect to be in each cell in the 411x13 matrix, then?

Comment: @tmrlvi when I was using the library to calculate Jaccard Similarity then I was getting an 411x13 matrix, that's why I'm surprised.

Comment: @hpaulj I see what you mean, when it's "jaccard_similarities = np.zeros((n_instances, n_instances))" then it's a 411x411 matrix. However I tried to do it "np.zeros((n_instances, n_features))" but then I got an error "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (411,) (13,)" when doing a loop.

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong!! I was getting an 13x13 matrix when using the library to calculate the Jaccard similarity. Too much time spent in front of the computer and I got a little silly hahah